# Unite two column tables together within SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

How do I unit two tables to a new table that doesn't include a primary key?

For example:

**First Table:**

```
Team_Code           ID
----------------------------------
433                 203994834
436                 203994834 
436                 309228372
435                 309228373
434                 309228374
433                 399064113
```

**Second Table:**

```
number_of_times       Team_Code
------------------------------------
3                     433
2                     434
1                     435
1                     436
```

**The first lines of the output should look like:**

```
number_of_times    Team_Code      ID
---------------------------------------------
3                  433            203994834
2                  434            309228374  
1                  435            309228373
1                  436            203994834
```

Comment: are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ? Please tag appropriately

Comment: there are 2 rows with `Team_Code 433` from first query, how do you decide which to take ?

Comment: Why did you choose `203994834` over `399064113` for `Team_Code` : `433`

Comment: I would like to take all of the. I didn't wrote all the table since its a long one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
; with 
query1 as
(
-- Your Query 1
SELECT * FROM Fireman_Team WHERE Team_Code in (
  SELECT Answer.Team_Code FROM Answer WHERE
  Answer.Call_Number IN(
    SELECT Call_Number FROM (SELECT * FROM Call WHERE Call.Time_Started
      BETWEEN ('2016-01-01 00:00:00') AND 
      ('2016-01-31 23:59:59')) AS SSS)) 
),
query2 as
(
-- Your Query 2
SELECT COUNT(Team_Code) as number_of_times, 
Team_Code FROM (SELECT Answer.Team_Code FROM Answer WHERE
  Answer.Call_Number IN(
    SELECT Call_Number FROM (SELECT * FROM Call WHERE Call.Time_Started
      BETWEEN ('2016-01-01 00:00:00') AND 
      ('2016-01-31 23:59:59')) AS SSS)
) AS re GROUP BY Team_Code
)
select *
from   query1 q1 inner join query2 q2 on q1.Team_Code = q2.Team_Code
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks but it writes Invalid object name 'query1'. and q1 cannot be bound.

Answer (score 1):

Use CTEs for readability -

```
WITH CTE1 AS 
(
SELECT [Team_Code],[ID] FROM Fireman_Team WHERE Team_Code in (
  SELECT Answer.Team_Code FROM Answer WHERE
  Answer.Call_Number IN(
    SELECT Call_Number FROM (SELECT * FROM Call WHERE Call.Time_Started
      BETWEEN ('2016-01-01 00:00:00') AND 
      ('2016-01-31 23:59:59')) AS SSS)) 
)

;WITH CTE2 AS
(
SELECT COUNT(Team_Code) as number_of_times, 
Team_Code FROM (SELECT Answer.Team_Code FROM Answer WHERE
  Answer.Call_Number IN(
    SELECT Call_Number FROM (SELECT * FROM Call WHERE Call.Time_Started
      BETWEEN ('2016-01-01 00:00:00') AND 
      ('2016-01-31 23:59:59')) AS SSS)
) AS re GROUP BY Team_Code
)

SELECT b.[number_of_times], b.[Team_Code], a.[ID]
FROM CTE1 a
INNER JOIN CTE2 b
ON a.[Team_Code] = b.[Team_Code]
```

Comment: Is the semicolon correct?  And does `WITH` get repeated like that?  I'd expect `…), CTE2 AS (…` rather than `…); WITH CTE2 AS (…`.